# HTML5 video source tag syntax

Tags: html, html5-video

When inserting a video in a website using a relative location its rather simple:

```
<source src="videos/video.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
```

However i need to insert a video file from a completely different directory.
Like "C:\Some\Folder\onthedrive\videos"

But the project is in: "C:\XAMPP\htdocs\projectname"

I have also tried these things:

```
<source src="file://C:\Some\Folder\onthedrive\videos\video.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
<source src="file://C:/Some/Folder/onthedrive/videos/video.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
```

What can I do to fix this?

**EDIT**:

```
<source src="file://C:\Some\Folder\onthedrive\videos\video.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
```

Actually worked, the webserver and browser recognised it, but due to security one of them decided not to load the file.

Chrome: 'Not allowed to load local resource'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to change "file://" to "file:///".

Why three slashes?
"file:///C:/etc" is a shortcut for "file://localhost/C:/etc"

you can find it here: [file URI scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme)

**EDIT:**

I downloaded the video that w3schools is using in there [example](https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_video) and my code looks like this

```
<video width="400" controls>
   <source src="file:///C:\Users\Gebruiker\Downloads\mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>
```

Make sure that you change the path to the url. So that it is matching with your file tree

Comment: Tried the  'src="file:///C:/etc/video.mp4" ', it did not work.

Comment: Try this: `src="file:///C:\Some\Folder\onthedrive\videos\video.mp4"`
or try this `src="file:///C:/Some/Folder/onthedrive/videos/video.mp4"`

Comment: (For some reason i can't edit my previous comment), but you have to write your full path to your video file after the "file:///C:\"
or "file:///C:/"